# How to determine number of vertices per cluster in R with igraph

Tags: r, graph, cluster-analysis, igraph, vertices

normaly when I want to determine the number of vertices for a graph I only need to write in my script :

```
library(igraph)
vcount('name of your graph')
```

And then I have it.

The thing is that I'm trying to determine the number vertices for each cluster (community) and I have no idea how to do it. Is there any function in igraph that could help me to do it?

Here's my code so far :

```
library(igraphdata)
library(igraph)
data("UKfaculty")
newgraph <- as.undirected(UKfaculty)
cluster <- cluster_louvain(newgraph)
plot(newgraph, vertex.color=rainbow(5, alpha=0.6)[cluster$membership])
```

[image]

Is there any function in igraph that could help me to determine the number of vertices per cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may do what you want. First, assign the community membership to the nodes:

```
V(newgraph)$community <- membership(cluster)
```

Now you can make a subgraph based on community and apply `vcount` to it:

```
vcount(induced_subgraph(newgraph, v = V(newgraph)$community == 1))
[1] 18
```

And use `sapply` to get the count for all 5 communities:

```
sapply(1:5, function(x) vcount(induced_subgraph(newgraph, v = V(newgraph)$community == x)))
[1] 18 19 27  6 11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot neilfws. It works like a charm and with some reading on igraph.org, I do understand why :)

Comment: @Jonathan This is rather inefficient though, especially for a large graph. All you need to do is count the number of occurrences of each integer in the membership vector, e.g. `summary(factor(cluster$membership))`

Comment: Absolutely! Depends if you need the subgraphs for something else, otherwise simply count the members.

Answer (score 2):

Try `table`

```
> table(cluster$membership)

 1  2  3  4  5
18 19 27  6 11
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an igraph function called [`sizes()`](https://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html) for this. You can use `sizes(cluster)`.

Comment: Love this answer, super concise and efficient, +1!